# How to pass data into bootstrap modal django

Tags: javascript, html, django

- I have a loop in a django template which iterates over
  objects.
- With every object I have an edit button which triggers a modal.
- I am passing id to every edit button which triggers the modal of that
  object id.

Modal is opening but problem is I'm not able to pass data of the object into the modal.

**template**

```
{% if prof %}
<table class="table">
    <tbody>
        {% for edu in prof.education.all %}
            <tr class="divbutton" style="height: 90px;">
                <td>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div style="padding-left: 40px; font-size: 20px;">{{ edu.degree }}</div>
                        <div style="padding-left: 40px; font-size: 20px;">{{ edu.school }}</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="align-middle">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div id="button_under" style="margin-right: 20px;" class="login login-button">
{#                                                                    <button class="btn btn-info js-update-book" data-url="{% url 'users:book_update' pk=edu.id %}" style="cursor:pointer;"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit</button>#}
                            <button class="btn btn-info" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#{{ edu.id }}" data-backdrop="false" style="cursor:pointer;"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit</button>

                                <!-- --------------------------- Update Modal--------------------- -->

                         <form action="{% url 'users:book_update' pk=edu.id %}" style="padding-left: 15px; padding-right:15px;" method="POST">
                                {{ form.errors }}
                                {% csrf_token %}
                            <div class="row">
                                <div id="{{ edu.id }}" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                                  <div class="modal-dialog">

                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                      <div class="modal-header">
                                          <h4 class="modal-title">Update Education</h4>
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="modal-body">
                                        <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <div class="field">
                                                    <label>Degree title<span class="red-txt">*</span></label>
                                                    <!-- <input class="form-control" type="text" name="degree" value="" maxlength="60" size="50"> -->
                                                    {{ form.degree }}
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <div class="field">
                                                    <label>School<span class="red-txt">*</span></label>
                                                    <!-- <input class="form-control" type="text" name="school" value="" maxlength="60" size="50"> -->
                                                    {{ form.school }}
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- works -->
                                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <div class="field">
                                                    <label>Start date</label>
                                                    <div id="datepicker1" class="datepicker input-group date" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
                                                        {{ form.edu_start_date }}
                                                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- does not work -->
                                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <div class="field">
                                                    <label>End date</label>
                                                    <div id="datepicker2" class="datepicker input-group date" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
                                                        {{ form.edu_end_date }}
                                                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                                            <br>

                                            <div style="text-align:center;" class="login login-button">
                                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg" style="cursor: pointer;" value="Save">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>

                                  </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**View**

```
class ProfileSettingsView(UpdateView):
    model = Profile
    form_class = ProfileSettingsForm
    pk_url_kwarg = 'pk'
    context_object_name = 'object'
    template_name = 'profile_settings.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
          return reverse_lazy('users:profile_settings', args = (self.object.id,))

    def get_object(self):
        pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        return get_object_or_404(Profile, id=pk)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProfileSettingsView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['prof'] = self.get_object()
        return context
```

**form**

```
class EducationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    degree = forms.CharField(max_length=40, required=False)
    school = forms.CharField(max_length=40, required=False)
    edu_start_date = forms.DateField(required=False,
                                     input_formats=settings.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS,
                                     widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'readonly': 'readonly'}))
    edu_end_date = forms.DateField(required=False,
                                   input_formats=settings.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS,
                                   widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'readonly': 'readonly'}))

    def __init__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EducationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.request = request

    def save(self, commit=True):
        edu = super(EducationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        edu.save()
        profile = Profile.objects.get(id=self.request.user.profile.id)
        profile.education.add(edu)
        return edu


    class Meta:
        model = Education
        fields = ['degree','school','edu_start_date','edu_end_date']
```

**Update**

```
class EducationView(CreateView):
    model = Education
    form_class = EducationForm
    pk_url_kwarg = 'pk'
    template_name = "profile_settings.html"

    def get_success_url(self):
          return reverse_lazy('users:profile_settings', args = (self.request.user.profile.id,))

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(EducationView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['request'] = self.request
        return kwargs
```

Answer (score 0):

Your view is using the `ProfileSettingsForm` and your `EducationForm` isn't used anywhere. If I understand the models correctly, you have one `Profile` which can be related to multiple `Education` instances.

So you need to have multiple `EducationForm`s in your view, one for each object to update (plus probably an extra empty one to create a new `Education`).

You should use Django `Formset`s for this, or more specifically an `inlineformset_factory` as shown [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets)

Comment: Please check the updated queston. 
EducationForm is being used in Education CreateView and it's working fine, Problem is in updateview, Existing values are not appearing in the form.

Comment: Yes, but as I said, your `ProfileSettingsView` doesn't have the `EducationForm`. The `form` variable in your template is the `ProfileSettingsForm`. You want to add multiple forms, one for each instance of `Education` in your `profile`.